# Change language code for existing languages

Tags: 9

My site has two existing languages with several pages of existing content. The language code for both are incorrect.  I need to change the language code for English from **en-gb** to **en-ca**. Drupal UI doesn't seem to allow that (see below).

[image: Drupal edit language]

How can I change the language code for an existing language ?

Comment: I don't think you can (easily), the language code is the config entity's ID, and will be referenced in a lot of places in the database as the literal string `en-gb`. As well as the ID itself you'll need to find a way to enumerate and update all those references too

Comment: Yeah I think you have to add the new language `en-ca` and then make the content use that language instead.

Comment: @leymannx I think you are right. If someone posts that the recommended method is to create the new language and copy over translations, I will accept the answer.